# Maximizing the number of nonnegative coordinates of $Wx$

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

I want to find good incumbent solutions to the following problem:
$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}$

Given a matrix $W \in \RR^{m \times n}$, find the maximum number of nonnegative coordinates of $Wx$, over $x \in \RR^n \backslash \{0\}$.

The following linear formulation solves it, however it's not efficient:

\begin{align}
  \max_{x \in \RR^n, a \in \RR^m} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^m a_i \\
  \text{subject to} \quad & \norm{x}_1 = n \\
                          & -U(1 - a_i) \le w_i^T x \le Ua_i ~\text{for } 1 \le i \le m \\
                          & a_i \in \{0, 1\}
  \end{align}

Here $U$ is a large enough scalar, say $U = n\norm{W}_1$.

I would like to run it on matrices with $m = 700$ and $n = 100$.

Comment: You can omit the $\le U a_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a comment on the MIP model. I assume that the constraint $\|x\|_1 = n$ is intended to eliminate $x=0$ as a solution. An alternative that works with probability 1 is to generate a random vector $r\in \mathbb{R}^n$ from a continuous distribution, say uniform over $[-1,1]^n$, normalize it so that $\|r\|_2=1$, and use the normalization constraint $r^\prime x = 1$. This works unless the optimal $x$ is orthogonal to $r$, which has probability 0 of occurring given that the distribution of $r$ is uniform over a region with positive volume. The reason I suggest this is that eliminates any binary variables added (either by you or the solver) to deal with absolute values.

As far as generating a "good" incumbent, you can apply a number of different metaheuristics. I tried a genetic algorithm (coded in R) on a randomly generated matrix $W$. The GA converges in under a minute on my PC using your dimensions (700 x 100), but to compare it to the optimal solution (computed using CPLEX) I scaled the matrix down to 70 x 10. (I tried 700 x 100, but CPLEX did not look as if it was going to terminate in what was an acceptable time for me.) My first trial at 70 x 10 produced an optimal solution with 54 nonzeros versus a GA solution with 51. A retry with a different random number seed yielded an optimum of 59 nonzeros and a GA solution with 57.

Comment: Your first paragraph is really helpful, the absolute values seem bad for optimization. Just that reformulation of the $x \neq 0$ constraint improves performance by at least an order of magnitude. Could you elaborate on the genetic algorithm?

Comment: Assuming you have at least some idea of how GAs work, there's not much to say. The "chromosome" is simply $x$, a vector double-precision values with somewhat arbitrary lower and upper bounds. I generated the $W$ matrix with values in $[-10, 10]$, and I restricted values of $x$ to the same interval, but that was just guesswork. The GA starts with a random population of several hundred $x$ values, using the number of nonnegative components of $Wx$ as the fitness value, and mates and mutates them until a generation limit is hit.

Comment: There is a nice GA library for R, which is what I used, with mostly default parameter settings. If you know R, I'm happy to share the R notebook.

Comment: I adjusted my answer above slightly. First, there was a typo in the domain of $r$. It should be uniform over $[-1,1]$, not $[0,1]$. Second, it's probably good practice in general to normalize $r$. I don't think it's really necessary when the domain is $[-1, 1]$, but in general you want to avoid very large (small) norms for $r$ since they will possibly force $x$ to scale in a way that could conflict with the "big M" (or, here, $U$) constraints.